# Method for reading text file is skipping lines

Tags: java

I am reading a text file that looks like this (see picture below)
[image]

But when am reading the text file using my source code below. Its skipping some lines (See image below)
 Notice that it only shows a1, a3, a5, a7 in that sequence.

[image]

Here is my code below which doesn't do anything special just reads the text file and saves it in Map.

```
public static Map<String,Boolean> readSaveBoardState(){

    BufferedReader buffRead = null;
    Map<String, Boolean> scannedSavedState = new TreeMap<String, Boolean>();

    try{

        buffRead = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(saveCurrentState));

        String position = buffRead.readLine();

        while (buffRead.readLine() != null){

            String[] splitDash = position.split("-");

            System.out.println(splitDash[0] + " "+ splitDash[1]);
            scannedSavedState.put(splitDash[0], Boolean.parseBoolean(splitDash[1]));

            position = buffRead.readLine();
        }
    }catch(IOException ioe){

        ioe.printStackTrace();

    }finally{

        try {
            buffRead.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
    return scannedSavedState;
}
```

I've been looking at this for 30 minutes now and I still don't know why its doing that. Can anyone help please thanks.

Comment: Not a major issue with this question, but try to avoid images of text. Being able to copy and paste and text from your question makes it easier to answer. Depending on your situation (size of file, and whether you want all the lines at once) consider using java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(...) to read all the lines into a List<String> from a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code you read 2 lines but only work with one:

```
   while (buffRead.readLine() != null){ // read a line

        String[] splitDash = position.split("-");

        System.out.println(splitDash[0] + " "+ splitDash[1]);
        scannedSavedState.put(splitDash[0], Boolean.parseBoolean(splitDash[1]));

        position = buffRead.readLine();  // read the second line
    }
```

Change to:

```
  while ((position =buffRead.readLine()) != null){ // read a line

        String[] splitDash = position.split("-");

        System.out.println(splitDash[0] + " "+ splitDash[1]);
        scannedSavedState.put(splitDash[0], Boolean.parseBoolean(splitDash[1]));

    }
```

Comment: It would be good to include changing `String position = buffRead.readLine();` before the `while` loop to `String position = null;` so the first line isn't skipped.

Comment: Thanks very much jens. You saved me a lot of time. I am the only developer here that's i asked so many questions. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the lines twice but storing the value only once.

```
 while (buffRead.readLine() != null){ // read here and ignore

            String[] splitDash = position.split("-");

            System.out.println(splitDash[0] + " "+ splitDash[1]);
            scannedSavedState.put(splitDash[0], Boolean.parseBoolean(splitDash[1]));

            position = buffRead.readLine(); // read here and use
        }
```

Comment: will also skip every 2. line becuase readLine() will be called 2 times - removed the downvote because you are simply pointing it out - it isn't that clear if you are quick reading your answer ;)

Comment: @DominikAngerer The code provided by TheLostMind is not a correction of OP's code. It is any the code of OP with comment where the error is.

Comment: As you can see i changed my comment :) there you can see that I removed my downvote because he is pointing it out what is wrong with that simple comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling readLine() 2 times in the loop: first time in the while loop condition, second time at the end of the loop. Ouput of first call is discarded as it is never asigned to any variable. 
This should work:

```
String position = buffRead.readLine();
while (position != null){
  ...
  position = buffRead.readLine();
}
```